# Por que o MongoDB não está salvando os dados com valores default declarados no schema dele?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Saudações dev's, eu declarei o schema de seguinte forma:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const TweetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
    content: String,
    likes: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now // Pega a hora atual que a informação está sendo criada dentro do banco dedados
    }
})

// Exporta um modelo com o nome 'Tweet'
module.exports = mongoose.model('Tweet', TweetSchema)
```

O arquivo responsável por criar o documento em si é este:

```
const Tweet = require('../models/Tweet')

module.exports = {
    async index(req, res) { // listagem de tweets ordenado pela data e tempo mais recente
        const tweets = await Tweet.find({}).sort('-createdAt')

        return res.json(tweets)
    },

    async store(req, res) { // criação de publicações
        const tweet = await Tweet.create(req.body)

        // Envia para todos conectados um evento chamado tweet, contendo as informações do tweet criado
        req.io.emit('tweet', tweet)

        return res.json(tweet)
    }
}
```

Porém quando eu faço um insert na minha collection assim:

```
db.tweet.insert({ author: 'Matheus Wallace', content: 'Testando MongoDB'})
```

Ele não insere um valor por padrão tanto do like, quanto da data, por que será ?

Minha conexão com o Mongo está sendo feita assim:

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()

// Extrai o servidor http que foi criado com o express
const server = require('http').Server(app)

// Habilita o servidor para ouvir o protocolo HS (websocket e http)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/twetter-clone', {
    useNewUrlParser: true // Informa ao mongoose o novo formato de URL passado no parâmetro
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // Passa a variável do io para nossa requisição
    req.io = io

    // Continua com o processamento do back-end
    return next()
})

app.use(cors())

// Faz o express utilizar o formato json para todas as requisições
app.use(express.json())

// Informa ao express para utilizar o arquivo routes para controlar as rotas da app
app.use(require('./routes'))

server.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started on port 3000'))
```

OBS: A versão do mongo que eu estou utilizando é a 3.6.10 e quando eu tento inserir um dado utilizando uma ferramenta como o insomnia(Método PUT) sem passar os valores default ele consegue gravar esses dados normalmente contendo as informações default, mas se eu der um find dentro do meu DB os dados que eu enviei via PUT pelo insomnia não são listados.

Comment: O schema esta correto, experimenta criar os dados usando o método create ou  então criando uma nova instancia do schema e depois salvando com save().

Comment: Ola @JustCase, na verdade estou criando a collection com esse comando, porém eu dei um refresh no Robo 3T e criou essa collection com o nome de "tweets" contendo todos os dados default da maneira correta. O que aconteceu foi que eu estava fazendo um insert de teste numa collection com o nome de "tweet" no singular. Só fiquei na dúvida em que parte do código eu estou criando uma collection exatametente com esse nome do plural ?

Comment: Eu editei o post acima, contendo o arquivo que eu estou criando a collection

Comment: Isso é um padrão do mongoose, ele que cria dessa forma. [Doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)